# Union of circles and polygon in leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am adding two circles and a polygon to a leaflet map. Here's my code which plots these three shapes. Is there any way I can get a union of these three shapes?

```
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 0, maxZoom = 18))
m <- leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(72.84320,20.43397,zoom=16)%>%
  #Add mouse position
  addMouseCoordinates(style = "basic", epsg = NULL,
                      proj4string = NULL, native.crs = FALSE)

#Runway Extremities
ARP <- c((72 +(50/60)+(32.67/3600)),(20+(26/60)+(1.54/3600)))
ptTop2 <- c((72 +(50/60)+(16.98/3600)),(20+(25/60)+(25.18/3600)))
ptBottom2 <- c((72 +(50/60)+(43.45/3600)),(20+(26/60)+(18.13/3600)))
ptTop1 <- c((72 +(50/60)+(8.64/3600)),(20+(26/60)+(8.08/3600)))
ptBottom1 <- c((72 +(50/60)+(44.21/3600)),(20+(26/60)+(5.63/3600)))
ap1 <- 95
ap2 <- 26

pt1 <- destPoint(ptTop1,ap1+90,4000)
pt2 <- destPoint(ptTop1,ap1-90,4000)
pt3 <- destPoint(ptBottom1,ap1-90,4000)
pt4 <- destPoint(ptBottom1,ap1+90,4000)
iRect <- data.frame(rbind(pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4))

#Inner Horizontal Surface
m%>%addCircles(ptBottom1[1],ptBottom1[2],radius = 4000,color = "red",
                    fillOpacity = 0,weight = 3)%>%
  addCircles(ptTop1[1],ptTop1[2],radius = 4000,color = "red",
             fillOpacity = 0,weight = 3)%>%
  addPolygons(iRect$lon,iRect$lat,color = "blue",
              fillOpacity = 0, weight=3)
```

`rgeos` has the `gUnion()` function, but I am not sure how to convert the circles that have been added by the code above, into SpatialPolygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend moving away from spatial objects from the `sp` package and instead look at simple feature objects from the [`sf` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html).

Simple Features are the 'new' spatial class for R (and are made by the same guy who did `sp`).

So, to get the union of your circles, you can use

```
library(rgeos)
library(sf)


## A dataframe of your points
df <- data.frame(lon = c(ptTop1[1], ptTop2[1], ptBottom1[1], ptBottom2[1]),
                 lat = c(ptTop1[2], ptTop2[2], ptBottom1[2], ptBottom2[2]))

## convert them into a simple features data.frame
sf_df <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c("lon", "lat"))

## convert into circles
sf_circles <- st_buffer(sf_df, dist = 0.04)

## find the union of all the circles
sf_combined <- st_union(sf_circles)


## now sf_combined is a single polygon
sf_combined
# Geometry set for 1 feature 
# geometry type:  POLYGON
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 72.79573 ymin: 20.38366 xmax: 72.88561 ymax: 20.47837
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# POLYGON((72.8745460445306 20.4072956786729, 72....
```

As for plotting, leaflet can handle `sf` objects (except for MULTIPOINT), so you can plot it directly

```
library(leaflet)

sp <- as(sf_combined, 'Spatial')

sf_combined %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `sf` package. This is exactly what I need!

Comment: @Dhiraj - you're welcome. I found it takes a while to get used to `sf`, but ultimately it's worth the effort.

Comment: **leaflet** does support all major **sf** classes but `MULTIPOINT` so there should be no need to convert to **sp** here.

Comment: @TimSalabim - you're absolutely right! I must have been out of date. Updated now - thanks

Comment: @SymbolixAU I am now stuck with trying to combine a polygon with the union of circles. I have a polygon `rect1 <- st_polygon(list(cbind(lon=c(pt1[1],pt2[1],pt3[1],pt4[1],pt1[1]),
                               lat=c(pt1[2],pt2[2],pt3[2],pt4[2],pt1[2]))))
` but when I try to combine this with the combined circles, I see no change `sf_combined1 <- st_union(sf_combined1,rect1,by_feature = F)`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. Whenever you add something on a leaflet map its considered as a separate layer, with separate properties and data:

- The idea is to be able to hide/show those layers using interactive
  legends (so you want to keep your layers separated)
- I don't see any simple way to access each circle's points' coordinates

If you want to display something that's composed of several shapes, you'll have to create a complex SpatialPolygon yourself with points coordinates, sp package and this kind of code:

```
require(sp)
require(leaflet)

#Used for sp polygon creation
createPolygon <- function(latitude, longitude, name = "polygon"){

  return(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(longitude, latitude))), ID = name))

}

#Will give "res" points coordinates for a circle centered on x0 y0
#with a radius r
CreateCircle <- function(x0, y0, r, res = 50){

  theta = seq(0, 2*pi, length.out = res+1)

  x = r*cos(theta) + x0
  y = r*sin(theta) + y0

  return(data.frame(x, y))

}

#Computes two circles points'
circleA <- CreateCircle (0, 0, 2, res = 200)
circleB <- CreateCircle (10, 10, 4, res = 6)

#Add them to polygons
A = createPolygon(circleA$x, circleA$y, "A")
B = createPolygon(circleB$x, circleB$y, "B")
C = SpatialPolygons(list(A, B))

#Create and display the leaflet map
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = C, fillColor = topo.colors(10, alpha = NULL), stroke = TRUE)
m
```

If it can't display the result you want (e.g. because you want the circles to have different colors than your rectangles), you will have to use several layers and group them.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Dallaporta I will definitely give it a shot. Could you please tell me how to draw circles as spatial polygons?

Comment: Sure, I added some code lines to the minimal example :). You'll need to design functions like "CreateCircle" if you want to display custom shapes on a leaflet map

Comment: @Kevin Dallaporta, thanks for all your help, really appreciate!